# Java program randomly getting stuck in Scanner.next()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to write a text-only program to play the Battleship board game, and am just recently encountering a strange error where sometimes, when entering a coordinate, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop on a `Scanner.next()` statement. Here is the section of code the error occurs in:

```java
102        Coord coord=null;
103        System.out.print("Please enter the coordinate of the square you wish to fire upon: ");
104        boolean loop = true;
105        while (loop) {
106            try {
107                coord = new Coord(scan.next()); 
108                loop = false;
109            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
110                loop = true;
111                System.out.print("Please enter a valid coordinate.\nPlease enter the coordinate you wish to fire upon: ");
112            }
113        }
```

The Coord class in this code is a small class I have written that handles coordinates on the game board, and its constructor can handle converting a string coordinate like `"A3"` into the proper coordinates. scan is a Scanner `object` initialized earlier in the code with to be a new `Scanner(System.in)`. Sometimes when entering a coordinate, the code will freeze up right after I input it. There does not seem to be any pattern to what coordinates cause it to freeze, or when it will freeze. Can anybody help me with this problem?

EDIT:
I forgot to add this on my initial post, but I ran the code in debug mode to track down the point it stops, [here is a link to a screenshot of the trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV3UJ.png).

EDIT 2: Here is the full code of the Coord class, as someone in the comments requested.

```java
public class Coord {
    /** Background class to handle coordinates
     *  can be initialized from either x,y coordinates, or an alphanumeric coordinate string
     */
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private static String yKey = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    public Coord(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public Coord (String coord) {
        String first = coord.substring(0,1);
        String second = coord.substring(1);
        try {
            y = yKey.indexOf(first.toUpperCase());
            x = Integer.parseInt(second) - 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinate: "+coord);
        }
        if(x<0||x>9||y<0||y>9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinate: "+coord);
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return yKey.charAt(y)+Integer.toString(x+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: for which `input` the error occurs?

Comment: Nothing in your paste is useful in determining why this is happening. Paste the full code (or at least, a lot more than this - where you make the scanner, what happens with that scanner before this, the code of the Coord constructor, when you say 'freeze up', do you mean 100% CPU spin, or just nothing happening, which line is it 'stuck' on (use debuggers/add Sysout statements), and what input are you providing to this application that makes it stuck?

Comment: @rzwitserloot my apologies for the lack of information, I am new to stackoverflow and was unsure how much information to put. I have added a debug trace I ran showing where the program stops. When I say "freeze up," I mean nothing is happening, when it should keep running. The same scanner object that's used here is used earlier in this code for other inputs, with no problems there. In addition, this problem does not occur the first time this code runs, but after it has run several times, and not always to the same input or on the same iteration.

Comment: Please add the code for your Coord class. Specially because the error is "random" as you stated you need to provide us at least a small reproducible piece of code so we can test. Read here for reference [mcve]

Comment: I have added the code for my Coord class, but I do not believe the problem is from this class, but from the call to scan.next(), as per the image I linked in the first edit

Comment: @des54321 *I did test your code. It is terminating smoothly for me.* It did not crash or freeze a single time.  Are you using any other classes along with these? Please also share on what particular inputs your code does not work. A simple example will help too.

Comment: The trace indicates it's simply waiting for input. There is still nothing in this question that seems to explain what you're observing, unfortunately. There is no need to apologize at all ;) - just trying to help you out. I'd prefer to help with a useful answer, but hopefully 'hmm, nothing in your question seems to be at fault for what you are witnessing' is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

After all the code you put:
`scan.close(); //Don´t forget this!!!` 
??
I don't know about running several scan.next() without after close the connection in the IDE you are using, but if you do this in a console does mess it up.
This maybe explains why sometimes it run, and others not.

Comment: If a Scanner is opened on System.in, then when it is closed, it closes System.in. If you close it at the end of your program, when you will never use System.in again, then it is alright to close it.